# How to check the value in comma separated data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column of `x` - `varchar2(4000)`, `y` - `number(10)` in a table `test`. I need a query which should write value `y` if condition matches.

column x has value like

```
x = 1,2 y =1
    3,4 y = 0
    4,5 y= 1
    5,6 y = 3....etc
```

the query should be if `x = 1` then query should writen `y=1`

if `x = 2` then query should writen `y=1`

if `x = 3` query should writen `y=0`.

Please help me in getting the SQL query with the mentioned above result set.

original data:

```
y  :     x
110:  953,954
110:  1153,1154
111:  1155,1156
119:  155,156
```

Comment: Use `CASE WHEN` statement

Comment: if x = 1 then query should writen y=1

if x = 2 then query should writen y=1

if x = 3 query should writen y=0. How are y values related , not clear from your question.

Comment: Hi, i can not use CASE as field X holds a value (1,2) . so i can not compare x=1, i f i do it will return null.

Comment: Y is a sequence number generated foe each row in a table.please find the given original data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this query:

```
SELECT x, y
FROM theTable
WHERE ',' || x || ',' LIKE '%,' || searchValue || ',%'
```

However, I must recommend you normalise your data

Comment: Can it be that your data is separated by a `, ` instead of just a `,`. The query above designed to work when the values are separated by a single comma, without the spaces. Check you data and report back here

Comment: yes..it is separated byy single comma.and it is working fine. thank u